# full email validation on Meteor using Mandrill

Tags: mandrill, meteor-accounts

I have read several SO posts about using Mandrill with Meteor.js for email validation, yet I've found a problem no others seem to face.

**Ultimately, I want the `verified` property of a user to be set to true after clicking the email validation url**. I am using Mandrill to send customized email templates containing a verification_url. I have the `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui` packages added. My code looks like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Mandrill.config({
      username: process.env.MANDRILL_API_USER,
      key: process.env.MANDRILL_API_KEY
      // port: 587,  // defaults to 465 for SMTP over TLS
      // host: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',  // the SMTP host
      // baseUrl: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/'  // update this in case Mandrill changes its API endpoint URL or version
    });

    Accounts.config({
      sendVerificationEmail: true
    });

    Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function (user, url) {
      var referralCode = Random.id();
      var result;
      try {
        result = Mandrill.templates.render({
          template_name: 'email-verification',
          template_content: [],
          merge_vars: [
            {
              name: 'SUBJECT',
              content: 'my fancy subject'
            },
            { name: 'EMAIL',
              content: 'my fancy email'
            },
            {
              name: 'VERIFICATION_URL',
              content: 'http://localhost:3000/?ref=' + referralCode
            }
          ]
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while rendering Mandrill template', error);
      }
      return result.data.html;
    };
});
```

When I create a user the verification email is correctly sent, however when I click the verification link within the email, nothing is done on the server, i.e. I look at my app's MongoDB and see on the user document still have the property `verified: false`. I've tried to work with onEmailVerificationLink (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-onEmailVerificationLink) but I get an error in the console saying onEmailVerificationLink has already been called, which happens because accounts-ui is apparently calling it for me. How do I do proper email verification in Meteor.js using Mandrill?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Instead of the line

```
content: 'http://localhost:3000/?ref=' + referralCode
```

I should replace it with

```
content: url
```

since Meteor is already creating the validation url for me, and passing it in through the "url" argument of the function. Clearly I didn't need referralCode either